# how to overflow text in excel C#/VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, excel

I need to overflow text of a cell that has too much data. I can't easily split it up into multiple cells so I guess the only choice now is to overflow it, but I just cant seem to find a way to do it.

```
wb.Cells(1, 1) = bigstring
wb.Cells(1, 1).WrapText = True
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "overflow"? Does the wrap text do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that they aren't displaying in the cell it is because the amount of characters displayed is cut off after 1024 characters. The value is still stored and you can see up to 32k characters in the formula bar.

```
    wb.Cells(1, 1) = bigstring.Substring(0, 3276)
    stringHolder = bigstring.Substring(32767)
```

Will store any leftovers that are too big for your cell to hold. I'm not sure if this is what you mean by "overflow" but it should let you handle any data that is too big to fit in a cell.

Another solution might be to add the large string to a comment box on that cell, so users could see the whole thing when they click on it without having to look at the formula bar